# Report when function fails

Tags: r

I'm looking for solution to send an email (or print a message to console/whatever) if a function fails.

Let's say that I have this simple function:

```
plus <-
  function(nr = 4) {

    return(nr + 4)
  }
```

If I execute it like this, I will get no error:

```
plus(nr = 7)
```

But if I do this, the function will end with an error:

```
plus(nr = "ten")
```

Is there a way to do something like this?

```
if (function plus fails) {
  print("FAIL")
}
```

Comment: You want this: https://adv-r.hadley.nz/conditions.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use "try"

```
result  <- try(plus(nr = 'ten'))
if(class(result) == 'try-error') print('fail')
```